# Query to Find Unique Records in a Historical Table

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to figure out the Oracle syntax to write a query to get all records from the below table that only have one DEVICE_ID record in my table called TEST.  So I would want the query to just return the 00005 TNT13232 record as only one of them exists while the others have duplicates.  Any ideas?

**TEST Table Columns:**

```
ID (auto generated sequence number 10)
DEVICE_ID (varchar)
```

**Example Data:**

```
00001 TNT12345
00002 TNT12345
00003 TNT12345
00004 TNT11111
00005 TNT13232
00006 TNT11111
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select device_id
from your_table
group by device_id
having count(*) = 1
```